# Automate Google Account Creation

Tags: captcha, google-checkout

Before I go to all the trouble of testing an approach and relaying the captcha, has anyone else automated Google account creation for the purposes of streamlining Google Checkout implementation?

Especially in a manner conforming to Google's terms of use.

Comment: How does automating Google account creation streamline Google Checkout?  Are you referring to a scenario in which the buyer does not yet have a Google account?

Comment: Exactly.  It's not really a professional-grade option for many applications to ask a consumer to go through the extra step IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a Google Checkout "Guest Account" - a one-time account where the customer does not have to create a Checkout account with a username / password.

Read the Google Checkout Terms of Service (section #7 - Time Checkout Account):

https://checkout.google.com/termsOfService?type=Buyer

This Checkout Merchant forum question has extra details:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/thread?tid=456542dc4fd031db&hl=en